# Referencing Primary Keys as Foreign Keys in other tables, SQL Server ASP.NET Web App

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a table to represent the following relationship in a er diagram in a asp.net web app using visual studio:

Administrator adds a Teacher
One to Many with total participation from the teacher entity as each teacher can only be added by an admin.

One admin adds many teachers, one teacher is added by one admin. Each teacher entity must participate in the relationship, not every admin participates in the relationship of adding a teacher as they may never add a teacher.

Table Schema
Person ID, Teacher ID, First Name, Surname, Date and Time, Person ID(Admin)

Other relevant Schema

Person (Super Class)
Person ID(PK), Name, D.O.B,

Student (Sub Class, Disjoint)
Person ID(PK), Student ID, First Name, Surname, D.O.B,  Age

Teacher (Sub Class, Disjoint)
Person ID(PK), Teacher ID, First Name, Surname

Administrator (Sub Class, Disjoint)
Person ID(PK), Administrator ID, First Name, Surname

So far I have tried:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Administrator's Teacher] (
[Person ID]  INT  NOT NULL,
[Teacher ID] INT          NOT NULL,
[First Name] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Surname]    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Person ID] INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Person ID] ASC) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[Teacher] ([Person ID]),
FOREIGN KEY ([Person ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Administrator] ([Person ID])
);
```

I think I cannot create the table because I cannot distinguish which Person ID I am referencing correctly? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Side note: Try to avoid putting single quotes/any special characters or spaces in your table or column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a many-to-one relationship between admins and teachers, the following should suffice:

```
create table dbo.Teacher 
(
    [Person ID] int not null primary key clustered, 
    [Teacher ID] int not null, 
    [First Name] varchar(64) not null, 
    Surname varchar(64) not null,
    AdministratorId int not null 
        foreign key references dbo.Administrator([Person ID])
);
go
```

Each teacher entry will be mapped to the admin that added it.  There doesn't seem to be a need for any join table here (i.e. a many-to-many relationship would typically require a join table).

Likewise, your column names are a little misleading.  Why do you have multiple identifiers for the roles?  I.e. why does an admin have an admin ID as well as a person ID?  My answer assumes so much about those IDs, but you should get the idea.

Just create a FK from the teacher table to the admin table to cover the 1-to-many relationship.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I see what you mean. I have been creating new tables when I should be augmenting a PK to act as FK in existing tables.